# How to use decorators (bottle.py)

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I am trying to use bottle.py to build some webpages. It seems like a major part of using bottle is learning to use decorators but I have read the python docs explanation of what decorators are but I am still not sure I understand them.

The docs say:

"A Python decorator is a specific change to the Python syntax that allows us to more conveniently alter functions and methods (and possibly classes in a future version)."

It sounds like you are calling a function with some changes made but I am not sure why you would do it this way or how to read the decorator.

Looking at some bottle code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\', '/')
    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555

    @bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')
    def server_static(filepath):
        """Handler for static files, used with the development server.
        When running under a production server such as IIS or Apache,
        the server should be configured to serve the static files."""
        return bottle.static_file(filepath, root=STATIC_ROOT)

    # Starts a local test server.
    bottle.run(server='wsgiref', host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

What does this line do `@bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')`?

If its a fancy function call then why do it this way rather than just calling the function?

Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this code:

```python
def my_decorator(func):
    return lambda: print("goodbye")

def greet():
    print('hello')

result = my_decorator(greet)
result()

--output:--
goodbye
```

The following is a shortcut to accomplish the same thing:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    return lambda: print("goodbye")

@my_decorator
def greet():
    print('hello')

greet()

--output:--
goodbye
```

The `@my_decorator` syntax takes the function below it, `greet`, and makes this call:

```
greet = my_decorator(greet)
```

The `my_decorator()` function has to be defined so that:

1. It takes a function as an argument.
2. Returns a function.

> A Python decorator is a specific change to the Python syntax that
>   allows us to more conveniently alter functions and methods (and
>   possibly classes in a future version).

Okay, so let's say that you want to *add* to whatever the greet() function does:

```
def my_decorator(func):  # func = greet

    def add_to_greet():
        func()   #<*********This is greet()
        print('world') #<***This is additional stuff.

    return add_to_greet

@my_decorator
def greet():
    print('hello')

greet()

--output:--
hello
world
```

> What does this line do `@bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')`

Okay, are you ready?  If the `@some_name` syntax specifies an argument, for instance:

```
 @wrapper('world')
 def do_stuff():
```

***First*** python will execute the following call:

```
 @wrapper('world')
 def do_stuff():
      ...

 #****HERE:
 decorator = wrapper('world')  #decorator is a newly created variable
```

The `wrapper()` function must be defined to:

1. Take any old argument, e.g. 'world'
2. Return a function that:

   1. Takes a function as an argument.
   2. Returns a function.

***Secondly***, python will execute the call:

```
 @wrapper('world')
 def do_stuff():
     ...

 decorator = wrapper('world') 
 #*****HERE:   
 do_stuff = decorator(do_stuff)
```

Whew!  Here is an example:

```
def wrapper(extra_greeting):

    def my_decorator(func):

        def add_to_greet():
            func()
            print(extra_greeting)

        return add_to_greet

    return my_decorator


@wrapper('world')
def greet():
    print('hello')

greet()

--output:--
hello
world
```

Now, let's analyze this decorator:

```
@bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
```

---

```
bottle  -- a module
route   -- a function(or other callable) defined in the bottle module
'/static/<filepath:path>'  -- a route
```

So the bottle module might look like this:

```
#bottle.py

def route(your_route):  #your_route <= '/static/<filepath:path>'

    def my_decorator(func):  #The decorator syntax will cause python to call this function with server_static as the argument

        def do_stuff(filepath):
            func(filepath)  #Call the server_static() function with the part of the url that matched filepath

        return do_stuff  #This function will be called when your code calls server_static(...)

    return my_decorator
```

> If its a fancy function call then why do it this way rather than just
>   calling the function?

Advanced stuff.

**Comment:** ***Perhaps you forgot to explain what specifically that route decorator does?***

---

> ```
> @route('/hello')
> def hello():
>     return "Hello World!"
> ```
>
> The route() decorator binds a piece of code to an URL path. In this
>   case, we link the /hello path to the hello() function. This is called
>   a route (hence the decorator name) and is the most important concept
>   of this framework. You can define as many routes as you want. Whenever
>   a browser requests a URL, the associated function is called and the
>   return value is sent back to the browser. It’s as simple as that.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html

A path can include wild cards:

> The simplest form of a wildcard consists of a name enclosed in angle
>   brackets (e.g. `<name>`)....Each wildcard matches one or more
>   characters, but ***stops at the first slash*** (/).
>   The rule `/<action>/<item>` matches as follows:

```
Path        Result
/save/123   {'action': 'save', 'item': '123'}
/save/123/  No Match
/save/      No Match
//123       No Match
```

---

> Filters are used to define more specific wildcards, and/or transform
>   the matched part of the URL before it is passed to the callback. A
>   filtered wildcard is declared as `<name:filter>`

---

> The following standard filters are implemented:
>
> **:path** matches all characters including the slash character in a non-greedy way and ***may be used to match more than one path
>   segment***.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to explain what specifically that route decorator does?

Comment: Perfect! This is very very well described! Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

A decorator is just a function wrapper, it takes some computable and surround it with more computables, technically a decorators is a function that returns a function(or an object, in fact there are decorator classes).

Lets say for example you want to make a logger decorator, this logger decorator will execute something and log who is executing it:

```
def loggger(name):
    def wrapper(f):
        def retF(*args, **kwargs):
            print name, "is executing"
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return retF
    return wrapper
```

So, we have our decorator that will print "Daniel is executing" before call our desired function, for example

```
@logger("Daniel")
def add2Nums(a,b):
    return a+b

>>> add2Nums(1,2)
>>> Daniel is executing
>>> 3
```

Bottle just works the same way, in the

```
@bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')
```

it just wrapps your `server_static` call so whenever some acces that route your function is called.